# The interval $(0,\infty)$ is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove this using interior points, $\epsilon$-neighborhoods and interior sets.  The interior of a set A is denoted $A^o$.  To show that $(0,\infty)$ is an open set, we must show that $(0,\infty)^o=(0,\infty)$.

Proof/Proof sketch:  Choose $c \in (0,\infty)$.  Let $\epsilon < c$.  Then $c-\epsilon > 0$ and $c+\epsilon < \infty$ for all $c \in (0,\infty)$.  This means that the neighborhood $J_\epsilon(c) \subseteq (0,\infty)$, hence $(0,\infty)^0 = (0, \infty)$.  We can conclude now that $(0,\infty)$ is an open set.

Any thoughts, clarifications, edits?

Comment: Let $\varepsilon$ be such that $0<\varepsilon <c$. Otherwise it's fine. One could also point out that $A^0\subseteq A$ holds in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fine approach. It is also ok to show that a set is a union of open balls (which is what you have essentially done) and note that a union of open sets is open to show that a set is open.

Comment: I just learned about showing that you can show a set is open by showing it is the union of two open sets.  I feel like in my proof that I've only shown that $(0,\infty)^o \subseteq (0,\infty)$ but not equality.

Comment: @Rye_yawn If you move on to point-set topology, you will actually take it as an AXIOM that any union of open sets is again an open set, and any finite intersection of open sets is an open set, in order to define a topology in terms of a base set of open sets that generate the topology. So your proof works on multiple different levels. Your proof actually shows $(0, \infty) \subset (0,\infty)^c$.